# How to change the default style of quake like terminal to comeout from bottom of page instead of drop down from top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

The Quake like terminal provided at 
[link](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#tilda)
has this animation of dropping down from top.I am trying to change its behaviour to come-out from bottom of page instead.Is there any simple way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add this css (after terminal css):

```
.tilda{
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```